# SUMIF (or something) over a wide range of columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a massive parts spreadsheet that I'm trying to simplify. Various parts could be included in number of locations, which I would like to add up to a single list. The attached file is just an example using reindeer.
[image]

This is doable with using a bunch of SUMIF statements added together, but not practical due to the range of columns I need to include. There's gotta be a better way!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=SUMPRODUCT(--($D$4:$J$11=$A4),$E$4:$K$11))`

SUMPRODUCT can do that. Make sure the second range shifts one column, but has equal count of columns (and rows).

`($D$4:$J$11=$A4)` results in an array of TRUE's or FALSE's for the value in range `$D$4:$J$11` being equal to the value in `$A4` (no `$` prior to it's row number will increase the row # referenced when dragged down).

Adding `--` in front of the array converts the TRUE's and FALSE's to 1's and 0's respectively.

Multiplying that with the range to the right of it will result in 1* the value in `$E$4:$K$11` for all TRUE's, which results in it's value, or 0* the value in `$E$4:$K$11` for all FALSE's, which results in 0.

Summing the array of values results in the sum of all values where the condition is met in the column left from it.

SUMPRODUCT combines the multiplication of the array and summing the array results to 1 total sum.

Comment: If generate a product, can omits the -- operator: eg ($D$4:$J$11=$A4)*$E$4:$K$11 returns 0 and 1

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this post. It returns an array (and may appear as `0` in older Excel versions).

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself well: `=SUMPRODUCT(($D$4:$J$11=$A4)*$E$4:$K$11)` works for me

Comment: Ah, that would do the same indeed

Comment: This is exactly the answer I needed. Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply the `SUM`:

```
=SUM((D$4:$D$11=A4)*$E$4:$E$11,($F$4:$F$11=A4)*$G$4:$G$11, etc.)
```

where in *etc* you can put any range you want. If you don't use 2021/365 version, you must confirm the formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.